# Redis connection error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque

I have a Rails app which uses Resque for background jobs. This works fine locally, but after deploying to Heroku I get a connection error:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
```

I see it tries to connect to localhost, which is not correct. I'm using the `Heroku Redis :: Redis` add-in and I have added the `redis` gem. This is how `initializers.redis.rb` looks like:

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
```

And this is my `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=* COUNT=1
```

In the config vars `REDIS_URL` is added. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when using Puma or Unicorn on Heroku, you need to add it also to the boot process. I'm using Puma, so I added this to `config/puma.rb`:

```
on_worker_boot do
  # ...
  if defined?(Resque)
     Resque.redis = ENV["REDIS_URL"] || "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
  end
end
```

Here is a more detailed explanation for both Puma and Unicorn:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#caveats